# Typescript person interface student class relationship

Tags: typescript

I've just started learning TypeScript. Have got a question for which I need your help.

In the below snippet, why there is no compiler error for the signature mismatch? How does the person & student are related here?

```
    class Student {
    fullname : string;
    constructor(public firstname, public middleinitial, public lastname) {
        this.fullname = firstname + " " + middleinitial + " " + lastname;
    }
}

interface Person {
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
}

function greeter(person : Person) {
    return "Hello, " + person.firstname + " " + person.lastname;
}

var user = new Student("Jane", "M.", "User");

document.body.innerHTML = greeter(user);
```

Thanks,
Gourav

Answer (score 2):

> why there is no compiler error for the signature mismatch?

Due to the vastly dynamic nature of Javascript, TypeScript is very forgiving on duck typing. Your `greeter` function accepts a `Person`, but it is virtually equivalent to an object with a `firstname: string` and a `lastname: string` property.

For the compiler, it doesn't matter if the given object is an actual instance of the specified class, an implementation of the specified interface, or just an object literal with the same properties.

The following are all valid uses of the `greeter` function. Object literal passed as argument directly:

```js
greeter({
    firstname: "John",
    lastname: "White"
});
```

Interface typed variable initialized with object literal and then passed as an argument:

```js
var somebody: Person;

somebody = {
    firstname: "John",
    lastname: "White"
};

greeter(somebody);
```

---

As for `Student` and why it's accepted: with the `public` keyword in the constructor, you automatically initialize the corresponding properties on the object instance. It is effectively a shorthand to:

```
class Student {
    fullname : string;

    public firstname: string;
    public middleinitial: string;
    public lastname: string;

    constructor(firstname: string, middleinitial: string, lastname: string) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.middleinitial = middleinitial;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
}
```

And since the Student class now has a firstname and a lastname property, and they are both strings, the Student class satisfies the requirements of the Person interface. It might be a good idea to explicitly specify that `Student implements Person`.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
class Student {
    fullname : string;
    constructor(public firstname, public middleinitial, public lastname) {
    ..//
```

Is similar to "after"

```
class Student {

        fullname : string;

        public firstname     ....// 
        public middleinitial ....// 
        public lastname      ....//

        constructor(public firstname, public middleinitial, public lastname)
```

When you make

```
var user = new Student("Jane", "M.", "User");
```

`user` infers types in this case `string`

```
class Student {

        fullname : string;

        public firstname     : string ....// 
        public middleinitial : string ....// 
        public lastname      : string ....//
```

and your interfarce:

```
interface Person {
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
}
```

When you say:

```
function greeter(person : Person)
```

you have to pass a minimum that meets the requirements of the interface.

Now you do something like `greeter(user);` user It has extra information so it works.

---

```
class Student {                                 | interface Person {
                                                |
        fullname : string;                      |
                                                |
        public firstname     : string = "Jane"; ->   firstname: string;
        public middleinitial : string = "M.";   |
        public lastname      : string = "User"; ->   lastname: string;
                                                |   
                                                |   }
```